# Analytical solution to an equation

Tags: polynomials

I'm just wondering if there is an analytical solution to this equation:
$$                 
15\left(\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{z^2}+1\right)z^2}-\dfrac{13}{\left(\frac{169}{z^2}+1\right)z^2}\right)\left(9-z\right)-15\left(\arctan\left(\dfrac{13}{z}\right)-\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)\right) = 0 
$$

Comment: Just wondering ... why? Did the equation come from somewhere that suggests it might?

Comment: Not really I just want to see if it does, just to learn the mathematics behind the solution. If it doesn't then the numerical solution is enough for me. This equation is used in an engineering context.

Answer (score 2):

An equation like this, with a mix of rational and trigonometric functions, is very unlikely to have a nice closed form solution (and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) seems to agree). Some of the approaches you could take to analyse the equation are:

1. Simplify it as much as possible. For example, expand out terms like $(\frac{1}{z^2}+1)z^2 = 1 + z^2$ and apply trigonometric identities to combine $\arctan x - \arctan y = \arctan(\frac{x-y}{1-xy})$.
2. Use a [numerical approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) approach like the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find an approximate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the graph, you notice that the root is close to $z=2$.

Make a series expansion around $z=2$ and then series reversion to get
$$z=2-t+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\, t^n \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{748225 \left(\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{2}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{756}{865}\right)}{1015752}$$

This infinite summation is an explicit solution of the equation.

The first coefficients $a_n$ being
$$\left\{\frac{46176237}{73218790},-\frac{1368517667332157}{2680495604532050},\frac
   {180071658879346903023413}{392525289528310434439000},\cdots\right\}$$

Using only the above terms gives as an *approximation*
$z=\color{red}{1.9428}05$ while the solution is $z=\color{red}{1.942811}$.

This was the result of the expansion up to $O(t^5)$. We can add more terms and for an expansion to order $O(t^{n+1})$ and obtain the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{approximation} \\
 1  & \color{red}{1.94}069388430155 \\
 2  & \color{red}{1.942}91205493791 \\
 3  & \color{red}{1.9428}0555882644 \\
 4  & \color{red}{1.94281}123395422 \\
 5  & \color{red}{1.9428109}0956042 \\
 6  & \color{red}{1.94281092}902546 \\
 7  & \color{red}{1.9428109278}1505 \\
 8  & \color{red}{1.9428109278}9239 \\
 9  & \color{red}{1.942810927887}34 \\
 10 & \color{red}{1.9428109278876}8 \\
 11 & \color{red}{1.9428109278876}5 \\
 12 & \color{red}{1.94281092788766} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Unig $n=50$, the error is $7.5 \times 10^{-60}$.

**Edit**

Just for the fun and without any meaning the solution is close tho the reciprocal of the positive root of the quartic equation
$$1420 x^4-2427 x^3+6599 x^2+1358 x-2216=0$$ for an absolute error of $\sim 10^{-20}$.

Plugging this solution in the equation as written, the value of the lhs is $-3.006\times 10^{-19}$.